# Cannot redirect from www to non www or from non www to www nginx

Tags: nginx

I've tried to send either www to non www and non www to www to have at least 1 redirect from both www and non www, and I ALWAYS get the welcome nginx page at the server from www (Already tried using incognito mode to prevent cache, tried different browsers, etc)

but this configuration is NOT

- Showing the build on [www.mywebsite.net](http://www.mywebsite.net)
- Redirecting [www.mywebsite.net](http://www.mywebsite.net) to mywebsite.net

Any help I will be good!.

also my DNS config is

`A      @      som.e.ip.4       600 seconds`

`CNAME  www    mywebsite.net.   600 seconds`

Thanks!

```
server {
server_name mywebsite.net www.mywebsite.net;
root /home/myuser/mywebsite/client/build;
location /api  {
               proxy_pass    https://localhost:3001/api;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.net/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
server {
    server_name www.mywebsite.net;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.net/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.net$request_uri;
}
```

Response from `curl -I https://mywebsite.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 30 Nov 2021 17:21:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 06:58:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: There, I found a way

Comment: Have you tested this using `nginx -T`? You seem to have a `www.mywebsite.net` in both `server` blocks - which should at least generate a warning.

Comment: @RichardSmith post the solution, so I can select it, this was it, the certbot generated an automated nginx configuration (on default) that was overriding my configuration on mywebsite and checking nginx -T I managed to see the warnings, I solved the warnings, and everything worked as expected, THANKS!

Comment: note also the curl example uses `mywebsite.com` - which is not in either server block.

Answer (score 0):

With @RichardSmith answer, you can also add the following snippet in both port 80 and 443 blocks:

```
if($host = www.yourhostname.com) {
   return 301 https://yourhostname.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do that. Granted, it will work to test `$host` in a server block but it means one server block that is overly complex (and inefficient, as that `if` is evaluated on every request) instead of 2 much simpler server blocks. It's also one of the examples cited for [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if)

Comment: Oh, I just found this as a solution on a digitalocean article, I thought it might be helpful

Comment: should I update the answer with another solution?

Comment: It's not a 'bad' answer, but there's a better way - I don't think anyone/Richard is going to mind if you point out the problem is all traffic is hitting the `server_name mywebsite.net www.mywebsite.net;` server block and mentioning the `if ($host` solution as an alternative (referencing nginx's own 'if is evil' docs). Generally on SO it's always best to improve an answer where new info comes to light.